# Magento 2 move block after another

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, adminhtml, extend

I want to add some new functionality to the order create view in adminhtml

Following magento 2 docs guide I just have to reference the block I want to extend, as far as I understood.
My block is recognized just fine but in at the wrong position.

I'd like to have it at the position where the `comments` are placed

Here is my layout
    app/code/Namespace/FancyModule/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="content">
            <block class="Namespace\FancyModule\Block\Rewrite\Order\View" name="custom.order.discount" template="test.phtml" after="comment"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

and here is the magento layout including the block I'd like my bloc to appear after/before

```
 <referenceBlock name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create" name="order_content">
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form" template="order/create/form.phtml" name="order_create_form" as="form">

                    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Data" template="order/create/data.phtml" name="data">
                      <!-- THIS ONE -->
                        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Comment" template="order/create/comment.phtml" name="comment"/>

                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to override the `Magento_Sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/data.phtml` template file. Copy this file to `{module_directory}/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/data.phtml` and then find line 80 which is where the comments block is rendered. Place the custom block wherever you like with this code:

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('custom.order.discount') ?>
```

Now in `{module}/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_index.xml`, set the `data` block to use the new template and add your block to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="data">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Namespace_FancyModule::order/create/data.phtml</argument>
            </action>

            <block class="Namespace\FancyModule\Block\Rewrite\Order\View" name="custom.order.discount" template="test.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Also, you should have `Magento_Sales` listed in the `<sequence>` element of your `module.xml`.

Comment: Thank you. I think that the whole magento layout extending thing is more complicated then it should be, but maybe it's just me having trouble with that

Comment: Cases like this where the layout is baked into a template file can be problematic, but most of the time it's pretty simple to add/remove/move blocks.